# RegGetValueA hard crashing application using luajit ffi

Tags: winapi, lua, ffi, love2d, luajit

I am trying to use the [`RegGetValueA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea) from the Windows API , but so far I've been unable to get any results from it. At best, I get a "file not found" error, and at worst it crashes hard without any error messages at all.

Below is the current code I have; I'm not sure what is and isn't relevant, and what might be causing the problem or not. I've only got a smidge of C knowledge, so please try to keep it simple.

```
ffi.cdef([[
        typedef void *  HKEY;
        typedef HKEY *  PHKEY;
        typedef unsigned long DWORD;
        int RegGetValueA(HKEY handle, const char* path, const char* value, int filter_flags, void* unused, char *result, DWORD* size);
]])

    local size = ffi.new('DWORD[1]')
    size = 1024
    local data = ffi.new('char['..size..']')
    local dptr = ffi.cast('char*', data)
    local lenptr = ffi.cast('DWORD*', size)
    test = reg.RegGetValueA(ffi.cast("HKEY", ffi.cast("uintptr_t",0x80000002)), "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Voices\\Tokens\\CereVoice Heather 5.0.1", "CLSID", 0x0000ffff, nil, dptr, lenptr)
```

Comment: I'm one hundred percent sure it can be found in the registry.

Comment: There are two registries in 64-bit Windows: for 32-bit applications and for 64-bit applications.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ffi.new`, what you get is a pointer variable, and you assign the pointer to `1024`, and then use `ffi.cast` to convert to `DWORD *`, which causes an access address conflict when calling `RegGetValueA`, so the program crashes.

You only need to modify the code as follows:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef([[
    typedef void *  HKEY;
    typedef HKEY *  PHKEY;
    typedef unsigned long DWORD;
    int RegGetValueA(HKEY handle, const char* path, const char* value, int 
filter_flags, void* unused, char *result, DWORD* size);
]])

local size = 1024
local data = ffi.new('char['..size..']')
local dptr = ffi.cast('char*', data)
local lenptr = ffi.new('DWORD[1]', size)

local test = ffi.C.RegGetValueA(ffi.cast("HKEY", ffi.cast("uintptr_t",0x80000002)), "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Voices\\Tokens\\CereVoice Heather 5.0.1", "CLSID", 0x0000ffff, nil, dptr, lenptr)
print(test)
print(ffi.string(dptr))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get a "file not found" error

This means "registry key not found".
There are two different registries in 64-bit Windows, you should try reading from both of them:

```
local ffi = require'ffi'
ffi.cdef"int RegGetValueA(uintptr_t, const char*, const char*, uint32_t, void*, char*, uint32_t*);"

local size = 1024
local pcbData = ffi.new'uint32_t[1]'
local pvData = ffi.new('char[?]', size)

local RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY = 0x00010000
local RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6432KEY = 0x00020000
for _, WOW64_flag in ipairs{RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY, RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6432KEY} do
   pcbData[0] = size
   local errcode = ffi.C.RegGetValueA(
      0x80000002,   -- HKLM
      "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Voices\\Tokens\\MS-Anna-1033-20-DSK",
      "CLSID",
      0x0000ffff + WOW64_flag,
      nil,
      pvData,
      pcbData
   )
   if errcode == 0 then
      break
   end
end
print(ffi.string(pvData))
```